# Linux timeout command doesn't timeout rm -rf path/test/*

Tags: linux, shell

The Below timeout command is not getting timeout since it's contain *

```
timeout 10 rm -rf /path/test/*
```

Could you please help is there any other alternative way to do the above , don't want to use find command and top that timeout having some issues with find command ,

What is the reason why timeout doesn't take effect when * character persent in a command

Comment: Note that you'd avoid this problem with `timeout 10 find /path/test -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -delete`

Comment: If there are too many results, `/path/test/*` may not work at all; `find` doesn't have a limit based on how many results it has, but your wildcard can expand to more filenames than can be placed on a command line at all, in which case the command will just fail. (There's an OS kernel-defined limit on the combined space available for environment variables and command-line arguments, and each wildcard result when you use `/path/test/*` on a command line becomes a separate argument).

Comment: ...you can avoid that limit with something like `printf '%s\0' /path/test/* | timeout 10 xargs -0 rm -rf`, since `xargs` will start additional copies of `rm` if there are too many files to fit on one command line -- though that too isn't applying the timeout to the process of reading the directory and generating the list. (OTOH, it's at least _explicit_ about that being outside the timeout's scope).

Comment: (well -- `timeout 10 find /path/test -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -exec rm -rf -- {} +`, replacing my first comment, given the desired recursion)

Comment: Anyhow -- @barmar's answer is a good one in general, but if you have a directory so large that `/path/test/*` takes more than ten seconds to list, you may also find that the results of listing it can't fit on a command line at all.

Comment: Thank you Charles , Appreciated for detailed explanation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem may be when the shell is expanding the wildcard, not while the `rm` command is running. Run it in a new shell process.

```
timeout 10 bash -c 'rm -rf /path/test/*'
```